# iOS: Facebook SDK location is null

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

Making the call:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad)
{
    .....
     [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        self.loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"]];
        self.loginView.delegate = self;
    }];
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {


    NSLog(@"User firstName From Facebook %@", user.firstName);
    NSLog(@"User lastNameFrom Facebook %@", user.lastName);
    NSLog(@"User birthday From Facebook %@", user.birthday);
    NSLog(@"User country From Facebook %@", user.country);
    NSLog(@"User Email From Facebook %@", user.email);

    NSLog(@"User location From Facebook %@", user.location);
    NSLog(@"User location.location From Facebook %@", user.location.location);
    NSLog(@"User location.location.country From Facebook %@", user.location.location.country);


}
```

Log:

//I get the firstName, lastName, birthday, country, and email just fine

For user.Location:

```
2014-04-19 16:37:16.143 App[56522:60b] User location From Facebook {
    id = 093483980708726711;
    name = "San Francisco, California";
}

2014-04-19 16:37:16.143 App[56522:60b] User location.location From Facebook (null)
2014-04-19 16:37:16.143 App[56522:60b] User location.location.country From Facebook (null)
```

I also tried, but no avail:

```
[user objectForKey:@"country"]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get back the Country?

Comment: According to what you Logs for `user.location`, it seems normal that there is no `user.location.location`

Comment: Yes.  It's coming back (null).

Comment: Do the user account has location data associated with it ? You can try some other account for logging in. Also, try to reset the simulator and delete the application permission from that Facebook account and log in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"Location name >>> %@", [user objectForKey:@"location"][@"name"]);

NSArray *tempArray = [[user objectForKey:@"location"][@"name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"City >>> %@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:0]);

NSLog(@"Country >>> %@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```